# Adding a System::String^ as key in VC++ Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, c++-cli

I am completely new to C++, so I'm stuck on something which I'm sure is trivial.

I have a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<String^, Room^>^ roomList = gcnew Dictionary<String^, Room^>();
```

I'm trying to add a new Room to the dictionary:

```
Room r("Room 1", x, y);
roomList->Add(r.getName, %r);
```

Room is defined as follows:

```
ref class Room
{

private:
String^ mName;
double mX; //scaled X-coordinate of top left corner (meters)
double mY; //scaled Y-coordinate of top left corner (meters)

public:
Room(String^ name, double x, double y); 

String ^ const getName() { return mName; }
double const getX() { return mX; }
double const getY() { return mY; }

};
```

When I try to compile the code I get the following error:

> 'Room::getName': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"

What am I doing wrong? For some reason I can't use the object's name (a System::String^) as the key, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   roomList->Add(r.getName, %r);
```

You declared getName as a function, not a property.  So it needs to be `r.GetName()`, note the added () parentheses.  Declaring a Name property would be wise, it is the .NET way.

```
   Room r("Room 1", x, y);
```

This declaration is technically wrong.  You are using stack semantics, the `r` object will automatically be disposed when code execution leaves the scope block.  You never want to add a disposed object to a collection.  You'll get away with it in this case since you did not actually implement a destructor.  Woe be you if you ever do.  And woe the reader of your code.  Just do it correctly:

```
   Room^ r = gcnew Room("Room 1", x, y);
   roomList->Add(r=>getName(), r);
```

Last but not least, this looks like a student assignment.  You cannot get a passing grade for this code, it is not C++.  The language you are using is called C++/CLI, it is an extension language that helps writing interop code for .NET programs.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. It helped clear some things up that were a bit foggy in my mind.  I assure you this is not a student assignment, rather my attempt to branch out from vb.net into c++, so the fact that it's C++/CLI won't incur the wrath of some professor.  However, most of the tutorials I've watched have been strictly c++, so I wasn't aware that you could declare a property.  Also, the concept of "stack semantics" to instantiate an object is new to me. I'll have to look further into that.

Comment: It was really a mistake from C++/CLI's designers to make "stack semantics on reference types" implicit. Especially for objects that don't even have a destructor/`IDisposable` implementation.

Comment: It wasn't, the RAII pattern in sacred in C++ land.

Comment: But managed types aren't designed for RAII, especially when they don't even have the required features. I'm not saying they should not have put it in at all, I'm saying they should have made it explicit (e.g. `autodispose<Room^> r("Room 1", x, y);`).